# C# XPath / formatting decimal places of variable type XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xpath, xmlnodelist

I am looking to format my year.InnerXml to 3 decimal places. I have tried things like String.Format but that doesn't seem to work. any ideas?

```
  XmlNodeList getYears = doc.SelectNodes($"/ghg-canada/region[{choice}]/source/emissions[@year >= {yearsEntered[0]} and @year <= {yearsEntered[1]}]");

  foreach (XmlNode year in getYears)
  {   
      string formatted = String.Format("{0:#,0.000}", year.InnerXml);
      Console.Write("\t" + formatted);
  }
```

one of the 'emission' elements looks something like: 16.55535068.

I am hoping to truncate it to only 3 digits after the decimal point.

currently, the emissions do not get truncated at all.

Comment: So how does the content of one of the selected `emssion` elements look? Which result do you expect, which one do you get if it things don't "seem to work".

Comment: I have edited the post and added that information

Comment: `InnerXml` is a sting, not a number to be formatted. Numeric format specifiers have no effect on a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `year.CreateNavigator().ValueAsDouble` instead of `year.InnerXml`.